# Visnetwork plot is not saved as png image

Tags: r, plot, visnetwork

I plot a simple network using `visNetwork` but when I try to save it as `png` I get an empty image as a result.

```
png("ex.png")
require(visNetwork, quietly = TRUE)
# minimal example
nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:3)
edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(1,3))
visNetwork(nodes, edges, width = "100%")
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save the network as html and then capture the content of that file:

```r
nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:3)
edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(1,3))

library(visNetwork)
plot<- visNetwork(nodes, edges, width = "100%")

html_name <- tempfile(fileext = ".html")
visSave(plot, html_name)

library(webshot); #webshot::install_phantomjs() #in case phantomjs was not installed 

webshot(html_name, zoom = 2, file = "ex.png")
```

Comment: Is there a way to increase the resolution of the webshot output. The quality  seems to be poor.

Comment: @scamander I've not used this that often, but you may want to use higher `vwidth` and`vheight` in `webshot` function (those define width and height of browser window). Even `zoom` argument may have something to offer. But as said, I'm not experienced in using this package and what I'm saying is merely based on skimming the documentation for 2 minutes with no further thinking (so it'd be complete nonsense). Looking at other functions in `webshot` package it seems that they are for *"lossless compression"* only. See here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/webshot/webshot.pdf for more info.