# Is it possible to programmatically export a list of networks one by one to PNG in the R package visNetwork?

Tags: r, visnetwork

I tried sample codes for `visExport()` and is able to add a "Export as PNG" button to a Shiny webpage. But this would need user interaction to press the button to export the network to a PNG image file.

I have over hundred of networks and would like to export them each to a PNG file. And some of these would need regular updating. So it would be logistically nice to be able to export all them to PNG files without a user pressing the "Export as PNG" button for each of the network.

So is it possible to programmatically export a list of networks one by one to PNG? This would be just like for `visSave()` to export the HTML for each network one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In reference to other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56654452/visnetwork-plot-is-not-saved-as-png-image), here is working code making use of the webshot package.

```
library(visNetwork)
library(tidyverse)
library(webshot)

# create network data
nodes = data.frame(id = numeric(),label=character(),set = numeric(),stringsAsFactors = F)
edges = data.frame(from = numeric(),to = numeric(),set = numeric(),stringsAsFactors = F)
for (i in 1:10){
  tempNodes <- data.frame(id = 1:15, label = paste("Label", 1:15), set = i)
  tempEdges <- data.frame(from = trunc(runif(15)*(15-1))+1,
                          to = trunc(runif(15)*(15-1))+1, set = i)
  nodes = rbind(nodes,tempNodes)
  edges = rbind(edges,tempEdges)
}

# loop through each set to export to PNG
for (i in 1:max(nodes$set)){
  subNodes = nodes[nodes$set==i,]
  subEdges = edges[edges$set==i,]
  network = visNetwork(subNodes, subEdges, width="100vw",height = "100vh") %>% 
    visLayout(randomSeed=1,improvedLayout=TRUE) %>% 
    visGroups(groupname = "actorImported",shape="circle") %>%  
    visEdges(smooth=FALSE) %>% 
    visPhysics(solver = "barnesHut") 
  fname = paste0("network",sprintf("%03d",i),".html")
  visSave(network,fname)
  webshot(fname,delay=0.5,zoom=2,file=paste0("network",sprintf("%03d",i),".png"),
          vwidth=900,vheight=900)
}
```

Comment: This was helpful. For my larger network, increasing the delay to 5 seconds gave it enough time to load the network.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer must be "Yes", but since you've not given us any sample code, it's impossible to give you a tested solution.  But you say you have a hundred networks.  Let's assume there in a vector `networks`.  (A list would work as well with minor changes to the sample code below.)  You can export one graph using a Shiny button.  So you must have code to create a single network image.  Suppose that's in a function `createImageForNetwork(x)`, where `x` is a network.  You'll also need a function to create an output file name for each image.  Suppose that's called `getFilename(x)`.  Then something like the untested code below will do what you want:

```
exportNetworkImage <- function(x) {
  png(getFilename(x))
  createImageForNetwork(x)
  dev.off()
}
lapply(1:length(networks), function(x) exportNetworkImage(networks[x]))
```

If you want to do that with a single button click in your Shiny app, then just put that code inside the button's `observeEvent` handler.

Comment: With all due respect, you might have misunderstand the question. visNetwork does not render to plot but rather to the viewer, so png() cannot be used to capture the image. As far as I know, visExport() only add a button to the webpage and it still requires the user to press the button in order to complete the process to export to PNG. So I am asking here if there are any methods beyond using visExport(). I found a working method later and will post it. Thanks for the effort.